# Multiple inheritance in Python - error when invoking __init__

Tags: python

I have a class `D`, this class inherits the classes `B` and `C`, which both inherit `A`, but when I created an instance of class `D` this error occurred:

```
johni@johni-pc:~/Draft$ python3.4 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    d = D()
  File "main.py", line 31, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "main.py", line 19, in __init__
    super().__init__("pg")
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I don't understand this.

The classes `B` and `C` are initializing the parameter `driver` in class `A`. My file `main.py`:

```
class A:   
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    @property
    def driver(self):
        return self.__driver

    @driver.setter
    def driver(self, valor):
        self.__driver = valor

    def run_driver(self):
        print("I am executing with %s" % self.driver)

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("pg")


class C(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("conn_pg")


class D(B, C):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


d = D()
print(d.run_driver())
```

Why did this error occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `super` ensures that *all* superclass methods get called, according to the MRO (method resolution order - see e.g. [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367/3001761)). `D` inherits from both `B` **and** `C`, so the following happens:

- `D()` calls `D.__init__`
- `D.__init__` calls `B.__init__`
- `B.__init__` calls `C.__init__` - **here is the problem!**
- `C.__init__` calls `A.__init__` - we never get here

It is not clear *why* `D` inherits from both - you can't have two `driver`s, surely? If you do need to handle this, note that all `__init__` methods should be written to take the same parameters, e.g. add:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
               # ^ ^ ^ ^ this part
```

to `B` and `C`.